# JavaScript temp variable

Tags: javascript

Hi this is the situation

```
var seat_sel = document.getElementById('cmb_num_seat').value;

var cashp = document.getElementById('hdn_price').value;

var CHILD_PRICE = '5'

if(seat_sel > 0){
    CHILD_PRICE = CHILD_SEAT_PRICE * seat_selected;
}else{
        CHILD_PRICE = CHILD_SEAT_PRICE * seat_selected;
}   
   document.getElementById('disp_2_div').innerHTML = formatCurrency(parseInt(cashp)+parseInt(CHILD_PRICE));
   document.getElementById('hdn_price').value = formatCurrency(parseInt(cashp)+parseInt(CHILD_PRICE))
```

For example...

i have `cashp=20` ,

When user select the `cmb_num_seat(DROP DOWN)` , Then Price will be increase That is

```
20+(5*3)=20+15=45
```

Assume i selected 3 in the dropdown...

But in some situation , Calculation goes wrong...

Like select 3 , and then select 4 and then select 2 and then selecting 1 ,

In this situation old   value hdn_price is over riding ...bcoz of ADDITION ...

Is there any way ...maintain first value in some variable and then doing the calculation...

Comment: Please show a complete function and how you call it. It is important. Also show the form fields.

Comment: My guess would be a scope issue, but like mplungjan said, we need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem is with your code or what you think it is, put I see several potential problems:

- You mix data types wildly.
- You use a variable that seems not to be initialised (seat_selected).

Also, you have an `if` statement that does exactly the same thing in both cases, and you initialise `CHILD_PRICE` to a string, but the following code always replaces it with a numeric value.

If you are going to do calculations on numbers, parse the values before doing the calculations. Don't be afraid to use a few more variables for intermediate values, it doesn't have any noticable effect performance, and it makes the code more readable.

If you want to keep the start price, you should read the value from the hidden field once when the page loads:

```
var price = parseInt(document.getElementById('hdn_price').value);
```

Then you use the variable in the update code:

```
var seats = parseInt(document.getElementById('cmb_num_seat').value);

var childPrice = CHILD_SEAT_PRICE * seats;

var display = formatCurrency(cash + childPrice);

document.getElementById('disp_2_div').innerHTML = display;
document.getElementById('hdn_price').value = display;
```